# Is it possible to use command listed in GlassVoice.apk but not enumerated in VoiceTriggers.Command?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I see a lot of commands in GlassVoice.apk from http://pastebin.com/PmiJjbHU on http://www.reddit.com/r/googleglass/comments/235oe5/google_glass_next_target_japan/.

If so can I use them? Should I use "com.google.android.glass.permission.DEVELOPMENT" permission?

The reason why I ask this question is that in Distribute page, I see "Glassware uses approved voice commands". I already see my approved command I committed months ago in that list. But not in VoiceTriggers.Command.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> When you want to start Glassware and have it appear in MyGlass, you must use one of the existing commands defined in the VoiceTriggers.Command enum (this also means a Glass system update must happen for new voice commands to work).

The answer I believe, is no.